# Copy data from one partition to previous partition

Tags: partition

I currently have my Ubuntu mounted on /dev/sdb7 and would like to move all the data to a previous partition.

The unallocated space is my partition, which I haven't created yet.

[image: The current partitioning]

Is there any way?

Comment: Welcome, format the unallocated space to ext4 , then you will be able to move your data. It can be done by right clic then format to.

Comment: But how I can move data around since I am using the partition?

Comment: Once you created the partition, you have to mount it, and then you can copy the data to it.

Comment: It's possible to clone your ext4 root filesystem to the unallocated space, but the filesystem cannot be mounted. Which bootloader are you using? Is your system MBR or UEFI?